# Узнать адрес сервера на Heroku, когда разместил там своё приложение

Tags: node.js, heroku

Здравствуйте. Я уже задавал этот вопрос но так и не разобрался с ним. У меня проблема в том, что я использую socket.io и в нем нужно указать адрес сервера, чтобы он мог отправлять туда запросы. Когда я работал локально, я использовал

```
'http://localhost:4000/'
```

теперь же я загружаю приложение на heroku и socket.io выдает ошибку. Мне в прошлом вопросе посоветовали использовать

```
port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
http.listen(port, function() {
console.log('server is working! '+ this.address().address);
test = this.address().address;
});
```

при загрузке приложения я сразу же делаю такой запрос:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
port;
xhr.open('GET', 'setHost', false);
xhr.send();
if (xhr.status != 200) {
  alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText );
} else {
alert(xhr.responseText);
port = xhr.responseText;
}
```

с process.env.PORT я получаю набор цыфр, с this.address().address - ::

и не понимаю что я должен указывать в

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:4000/'); //Здесь вместо локал хост
```

или я не правильно пытаюсь узнать путь к серверу. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Извиняюсь, все решилось таким путём:

```
const socket = io(''+window.location);
```